# Unittest a Python function's return value with empty user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, testing, python-unittest

I have a function inside `fruit.py` script that returns an Enum based on user input.

```py
class Selection((IntEnum):
    APPLE = 0
    ORANGE = 1
    PEAR = 2
    MELON = 3
    GRAPE = 4

def get_input():
    selection = int(input("Input an integer from 0 to 4: "))
    fruit = Selection(selection)
    return fruit
```

Now I want to test in `fruit_test.py` if it will return nothing/raise error if the user input is empty:

```py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch
import fruit

class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    @patch('builtins.input', return_value=int(''))
    def test_empty_input(self, input):
        result = fruit.get_input()
        self.assertEqual(result, "")
```

But my test failed with `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''`. I understand this is because my patch input `int('')` is wrong but I don't know how to write the correct testing format. Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: The test is telling you the right thing - that's **not** currently the correct expectation, your implementation doesn't return an empty string if the input can't be parsed as an integer. So either the implementation needs to change, or the test needs to reflect what you _do_ expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert your get_input function to the following way :

```
def get_input():
    selection = input("Input an integer from 0 to 4: ")
    if not selection.isnumeric() or not int(selection) Selection.__members__.values():
       return None # or False or "" or whatever you want
    fruit = Selection(int(selection))
    return fruit
```

Comment: Is it possible to test without modifying `get_input()` function? For example, I know empty input will raise error `TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'` and 8 will raise `ValueError: 8 is not a valid Selection` Is there ways to test these exceptions and errors? Is just `AssertRaises()` enough?